# Overlapping Ovals

Tags: unity

So I am instantiating 2 ovals/ellipses at runtime with random rotations. The first oval will always be spawned at the center. However, the second oval must be placed in a way that should always intersect/overlap the first oval, something like a Venn Diagram. How would I do so? We are talking 2D and the ovals are sprites

Comment: Can the ovals differ in size or shape or do they only differ in rotation?

Comment: Are there any constraints on the size / aspect ratio / relative orientations of the ovals, or the amount of overlap? Any bit of specificity can help us make simpler answers with more reliably desirable results.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the length of the distance from the middle of the sprite to the closest point on the outside of the oval (which can either be guessed and then adjusted or produced mathematically), then a reasonable approximation for the second ovals location would be `new Vector2(oval1minDist + oval2minDist - offset, 0)`, where offset is a small but not negligible value. This ensures your ovals will always overlap by at least `offset` pixels. However, this solution doesn't account for the case where the ovals are long and skinny, in which case the ovals may form a cross.